# WiFi not available in Ubuntu 23.20 NetworkManager on Dell Latitude 5580 - works fine in Windows10

Tags: networking, network-manager, dell

1. I verified that NetworkManager is enabled & active (running).

   ```
   systemctl status NetworkManager
   ```

   [image]
2. I Updated NetworkManager with

   ```
   sudo apt install network-manager
   sudo apt upgrade network-manager
   ```
3. I ran

   ```
   $~ sudo lshw -C network
   ```

   [image]